# Kubernetes nginx-ingress isnt exposing the services

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to achieve following, I have installed Kube cluster (version 1.18) using kops on AWS EC2. It's up and running but now I want to expose some workloads to the internet to be available via subdomains but it isnt working as expected and I use ingress for that.

More details below:

```
Client Version: v1.18.3
Server Version: v1.18.3

helm version --short
Client: v2.17.0+ga690bad
Server: v2.17.0+ga690bad
```

***Chart is below:***

```
deploy.yaml:
    
        name: custom-smscs
        branch: k8s
        git: git@github.com:REDACTED
        
        image:
          repository: <account_id>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/custom_smscs
        
        service:
          port: 80
          internalPort: 80
          healthEndpoint: /health
```

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-deployment"
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: {{ .Values.environment }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.service.healthEndpoint }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.service.healthPeriod }}
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: {{ .Values.service.healthThreshold }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
```

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.name }}-service"
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  selector:
          app: "{{ .Values.name }}"
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  {{- if .Values.service.ports }}
  {{- range $name, $port := .Values.service.ports }}
  - port: {{ $port }}
    targetPort: {{ $port }}
    protocol: TCP
    name: {{ $name }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.name }}
```

ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: customsmscs.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: {{ .Values.name }}-service
            servicePort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
```

values.yaml:

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: replaced
  tag: "0.0.1"
  pullPolicy: Always
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  name: replaced
  port: 80
  internalPort: 80
  healthEndpoint: /health
  healthPeriod: 30
  healthThreshold: 3
environment: production
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 256m
    memory: 256Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  target: 80
```

The nginx was installed using following command:

```
kc apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.46.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy-tls-termination.yaml
```

There is everything required to run the nginx-ingress correctly:

```
    kc -n ingress-nginx get po
    NAME                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
    ingress-nginx-admission-create-qltch       0/1     Completed   0          154m
    ingress-nginx-admission-patch-6ll84        0/1     Completed   0          154m
    ingress-nginx-controller-b4678dfcb-8gn56   1/1     Running     0          154m
```

```
    kc get all | grep custom
pod/custom-smscs-deployment-6cd5f58bb8-ht49w   1/1     Running   0          37m
service/custom-smscs-service   ClusterIP   100.70.5.207     <none>        80/TCP            37m
deployment.apps/custom-smscs-deployment   1/1     1            1           37m
replicaset.apps/custom-smscs-deployment-6cd5f58bb8   1         1         1       37m
```

```
    kc get ing
    NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS                                   ADDRESS                                                                   PORTS   AGE
   custom-smscs-ingress   <none>   customsmscs.my-domain.com   <ELB>.amazonaws.com   80      38m
```

```
    kc get ep
    NAME                   ENDPOINTS                               AGE
    custom-smscs-service   100.101.173.27:80                       40m
```

But when I do describe the ingress i noticed some error, not sure it's a reason or not:

nginx log:

```
    I0525 09:47:46.702227       6 controller.go:146] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
    I0525 09:47:46.780938       6 controller.go:163] "Backend successfully reloaded"
    I0525 09:47:46.781209       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-b4678dfcb-8gn56", UID:"d5d9246b-63a8-4eba-8467-fdec0f3f9b3f", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"89646", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
    I0525 09:48:19.528969       6 status.go:284] "updating Ingress status" namespace="default" ingress="custom-smscs-ingress" currentValue=[] newValue=[{IP: Hostname:<ELB>.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com Ports:[]}]
    I0525 09:48:19.533791       6 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"custom-smscs-ingress", UID:"309890dd-1148-4aa8-bc14-62e57bbd969f", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"267393", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
```

**<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>**

```
        kc describe ing custom-smscs-ingress
    Name:             custom-smscs-ingress
    Namespace:        default
    Address:          <ELB>.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
    Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
    Rules:
      Host                                   Path  Backends
      ----                                   ----  --------
      customsmscs.my-domain.com  
                                             /   custom-smscs-service:80 (100.101.173.27:80)
    Annotations:                             kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    Events:
      Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
      ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
      Normal  Sync    43m (x2 over 43m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

So everything is looking good apart from the error above but when im trying to open an app.example.com in the browser im getting "Hmmm… can't reach this page". But when I open the ELB DNS endpoint URL in the browser I get "404 not found" which I guess is correct response as I called a default backend.

Another thing I noticed is that on the ELB there is only one of two nodes is in service:

[image]

I'm literally have spent 4 days on it but can't make it working.

Do you have any idea how to fix/overcome it guys?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you remove the pathType in ingress and retry?

Comment: Hi Taybur, thanks for the response. I will do.

Comment: That didnt help :-( 
Nginx log is looking ok but still the URL isnt working and in the ELB there is one of two nodes is unhealthy.

Comment: Yamls files without their values are kind of useless. Please update those using `helm template`. Another test would be to do check with curl and update the errors that you have. Lastly, how does the browser knows know how to reach the ip/address behind `app.example.com`?

Comment: Hi Thomas,

> Yamls files without their values are kind of useless. Please update those using helm template.

makes sense, i have moved the ingress.yaml into the Chart folder of the app where the values.yaml is and redeployed and now I see there is a new issue appeared in nginx log:
W0525 08:31:29.845867       6 controller.go:981] Service "default/app-service" does not have any active Endpoint.

and I see that endpoint really doesnt exists:
kc get ep -o wide
NAME                   ENDPOINTS                               AGE
app-service   <none>                                  7m36s

Comment: > Lastly, how does the browser knows know how to reach the ip/address behind app.example.com?

good spot. can you please shed any light about what I'm missing there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Denis, how would you like us to give u any advice over the internet if we don't see the actual values in the question? Not having any endpoints means your service selector and pod labels don't match.

Comment: @thomas, I have updated the post with the actual values. As well, I have updated service selector and now it has the endpoint.

Comment: Awesome. Now what please make some test with curl and describe in the question what you tried and what error it produced.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, the solution was so easy....
I have added DNS A record (alias) like *.ks8.my-domain.com pointing to the ingress ELB and created an SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager, as well there is one change I had to do, in the *ingress.yaml* the *host: * parameter should be changed to *customsmscs.k8s.my-domain.com* instead of *customsmscs.my-domain.com*.
And then I deleted the deployment and all related resources (ingress, service, etc) and redeployed it and now the app is available at the https://customsmscs.k8s.my-domain.com.

Thanks @thomas for advice, you helped me a lot!